# Strip code of all attributes and styling

Tags: jquery, html, code-cleanup

When uploading products onto my website I normally copy information from the manufacturers website and paste into my websites wysiwyg editor. This also copies all attributes and styling that I don't want/need.

I've created a file that strips this code of all attributes and styling so that I can add my own. This is to be used by someone without any knowledge of HTML at all so I'd like to know if theres a better way to do this than the method I've chosen.

There's some styling attached to the current div so that when it gets removed there's visual feedback that the code has been cleaned.

```
<button>Clean up code</button>

<div class="test" id="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;">

    <!-- PASTE YOUR CODE UNDER HERE -->

</div>

<script>


$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $("p").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("a").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("img").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("h1").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("h2").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("h2").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("h2").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("h3").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("h4").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("h5").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("h6").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("table").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("td").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("tr").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("ol").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("ul").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("li").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $("tbody").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");    
    $("span").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
    $( "div" ).contents().unwrap();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*`, which basically selects all the elements. Also `removeAttrs` can be a space-separated list of attributes.

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $("*").removeAttr("class id style");
    $("div").contents().unwrap();
});
```

Comment: I knew there was an easier way. I did try to separate the attributes but I used comma-separation and quoted each attribute individually which was obviously wrong - removeAttr("class", "id", "styles").

Comment: If I wanted to also unwrap() all span tags, how can this be done? I've tried $("span").contents.unwrap() with no luck and the only solutions I can find online seem to use quite a few more lines of code than I expected. The contents().unwrap() works with table elements so I would've thought that would work too.